# Declaring global variable of <vector>, the code will can't run successfully

Tags: c++, g++

This below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> vec;

int main() {
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I use g++ to compile the code.It can be compiled successfully,but I can't see anything in CMD when I run the code.Then I delete the line:

```
vector<int> vec;
```

The code can print "Hello World!" in CMD.

Questions:

1. If we can't use global variable of vector?
2. Why the situation occurs?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I don’t seem to be able to reproduce your issue. Which g++ version and what platform?

Comment: g++ version:8.2.0-3  OS:Windows 10.  I am sorry for that, thank you for your reminder and reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran this code on visual studio , gcc and on g++. Its result is hello world with or without "vector vec;".

please check it again..

Which command you are executing for compiling;

like this  :-   g++ program_name -o any_name

or something else.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I use the command of g++ program_name -o any_name.After I compile the code with "vector<int> vec" successfully, I run the program.But the system warn me that "The procedure entry point ~ could not be located ~ " !

Comment: Try this  g++ file -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -o file                                 (working fine)

Comment: Did you set path for gcc ?? 

If your path is set , and still you are getting same error .. Then you have to install gcc latest version on your pc and that might fix your problem.

Comment: I try the command  g++ file -static-libstdc++ -o file, which makes the code with "vector<int>" build and run successfully. But I am also interested in what cause this situation, could you give me some cules?

Comment: I think that this might occur when compiler did'nt find the std lib on run time..